# Emacs Prelude - Enable Python Indentation

Tags: emacs24, emacs-prelude

Having installed emacs24 on ubuntu and preude via curl. I wanted to enable python support so I created sayth.el in the personal directory and added (require 'prelude-python)

After restarting though I still don't have any python support and no indentation support.

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I created sayth.el in the personal directory and added (require 'prelude-python)

I strongly doubt Emacs will know about `sayth.el`. Instead,

1. Open emacs and do `C-h v user-emacs-directory`. This will probably be `~/.emacs.d`, but it's wise to check.
2. Check for `prelude-modules.el` in the emacs user directory. If that file is not there, there's another problem. If it's there,
3. Open `prelude-modules.el` in emacs and uncomment the line containing `(require 'prelude-python)`. (If it's already uncommented, there's another problem.)
4. Save the file, exit emacs, and restart it.

> Having installed emacs24 on ubuntu and [prelude] via curl

Just checking: did you install Prelude using [Batsov's directions](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude#readme)?

Comment: I used the fast forward instructions on the prelude website.    $ curl -L https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/raw/master/utils/installer.sh | sh

Comment: Any `.el` files in `~/.emacs.d/personal/` get loaded, not just `custom.el`, so putting your customisations in `sayth.el` should work too.

Comment: Note: batsov disables indentation in `prelude-custom.el` - see `defcustom prelude-indent-sensitive-modes`